# Magento - tracking who to give back to

Tags: magento

We have a Magento multi-site that give a percentage back to a non-profit, and what we would like to do is to allow customers to select which non-profit or a group within that non-profit to receive the percentage.

Trying to keep it simple we thought allowing customers to enter a discount code named something like "GIVE BACK to {non-profit name}" (but no actual dollar amount subtracted from the purchase or maybe just a penny, I don't think you can have a 0 to a discount code), then internally we know to give the percentage back to that non-profit.

It just seems a little bit of an odd way of doing this, it would be better to have a drop down of the none-profits at the end, but we are not sure how to create that.

Does anyone have any suggestions, on an easy way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an attribute to the quote/order model and then populate that with an appropriate value, populated at the cart level?  It's the kind of think we've done for affiliate modules we've built in the past.

You'll need a custom controller to grab the value when the customer moves from the cart to the checkout, which means you'll also need to make the `Cart -> Checkout` step a form submission instead of a straight link.

Then, at the end of the month, you'll need to run a report on the collection with something along the lines of:

```
// I've added a * in the SELECT because I'm not sure of the attribute names off the top of my head :)
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    // Make sure the orders are in the correct date range
    ->addAttributeToFilter(...)
    // Make sure the orders are in a valid state, e.g. processing, pending, complete, etc..
    ->addAttributeToFilter(...)

$donation_total = array();
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    // You'll have to investigate the attribute values for these
    $charity = $order->getData('charity_attribute_code');
    $order_total = $order->getData('order_total_attribute_code');

    if (!isset($donation_total[$charity])) {
        $donation_total[$charity] = 0;
    }

    $donation_total[$charity] += $order_total;
}

print_r($donation_total);
```

You could make this more efficient with proper `SUM()`ing in the query.